# PHP multipart/form-data Curl not work with IMGCLICK.NET

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data

I'm trying to remote upload a picture to IMGCLICK.NET using php cURL.

i can login and get/save cookie, But i can not send remote upload to imgclick.net

```
$url = "http://main.imgclick.net/cgi-bin/upload_file.cgi?upload_id=177781809062&js_on=1&utype=reg&upload_type=url";


$data = array(
'sess_id'=> "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 
'upload_type' => 'url', 
'srv_htdocs_url' => 'http://main.imgclick.net', 
'url_mass' => 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/PHP_Logo.png', 
'resize' => '0', 
'thumb_size' => '300x300', 
'to_folder' => '0', 
'per_row' => '1', 
'file_adult' => '1',
'tos' => '1',
'submit_btn' => ' Upload! ',
);


$headers = array(
'Host: main.imgclick.net',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0',
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Referer: http://imgclick.net/',
'Cookie: __cfduid=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; _ga=GA1.2.479494208.1429287148; login=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; xfss=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; lang=english; _gat=1',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------3323168743628',
'Content-Length: 1231',
);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $http_agent );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://imgclick.net/' );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $codeweb = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close( $ch );
print_r($codeweb );
```

i use Values in this code to Fiddler and it run, but with PHP is not.
Please tell me know what happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the upload url:**

You are submitting the wrong form.

Without javascript you may not be able to get the upload id.

When you are on the Upload page you must have JavaScript to initialize the upload request.

[image: upload]

Once you click on the above "Upload!" JavaScript takes over and sets up the POST request.

The upload POST request happens when you select the file you want to upload.

This is the file upload **POST request URL**:

```
http://main.imgclick.net/cgi-bin/upload_file.cgi?upload_id=577123813886&js_on=1&utype=reg&upload_type=file
```

**Cookies:**

```
Cookie: __cfduid=dcf8c69fbd9ebae2b5d7e75a56bfd792d1430683122
lang=english
login=login name
xfss=jsjl59xvxw0t3kme
```

**header and contents**

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=
Content-Length: 34688
name="upload_type"
form-data; name="sess_id" jsjl59xvxw0t3kme
name="srv_htdocs_url" http://main.imgclick.net
name="file_0"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
name="file_0"; 
filename="3zyw5t3yqfru21pdt2wnxazq0271085619.2.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[contents of the image files go here]
```

Comment: I know, this is Upload file on machine. but i want ask way to upload via Romote method (remote link)